# Privacy condition in a table view

Tags: postgresql

i have a table with two key columns, which are user and privacy. My idea is to write table view to query my table with reference to the relevant column.

I want a table view which consists of following condition:

```
 user=current_user()AND privacy = "TRUE"
 + user!=current_user() AND privacy="FALSE"
```

So what I want is the view displays current_users and private entries and those which are not switched to private.

What is the best way to do this. Is an if else statement or where argument efficient?

Comment: Probably the [Row Security Policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html) can be useful (required at least 9.5 PostgreSQL version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, a user should see his own entries and others' entries which are not marked as private.

Given the table (changed `user` to `usr` because it's a reserved keyword:

```
db=# create table entries(id serial, message text, usr text, is_private boolean); 
CREATE TABLE
```

And the following test data:

```
db=# insert into entries(message, usr, is_private) values
  ('postgres private entry', 'postgres', true),
  ('postgres public entry', 'postgres', false),
  ('test private entry', 'test', true),
  ('test public entry', 'test', false);
INSERT 0 4
```

You can define the view as follows:

```
db=# create view entries_v as
  select * from entries
  where usr = current_user or not is_private;
CREATE VIEW
```

What does `postgres` see:

```
db=# \c - postgres
You are now connected to database "db" as user "postgres".

db=# select * from entries_v;
 id |        message         |   usr    | is_private 
----+------------------------+----------+------------
  1 | postgres private entry | postgres | t
  2 | postgres public entry  | postgres | f
  4 | test public entry      | test     | f
(3 rows)
```

And now `test`:

```
db=# \c - test
You are now connected to database "db" as user "test".

db=> select * from entries_v;
 id |        message        |   usr    | is_private 
----+-----------------------+----------+------------
  2 | postgres public entry | postgres | f
  3 | test private entry    | test     | t
  4 | test public entry     | test     | f
(3 rows)
```